# Hibernate + JSF

Tags: dao, hibernate

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно организовать доменную модель?

На сколько я понимаю есть POJO - простой класс с полями и гетерами и сетерами.

Теперь собственно вопрос: какой класс должен реализовывать методы, отвечающие за обработку запросов (например добавить, удалить, изменить и т.д.)? Может создать новый класс сервис, чтобы не засорять модель?

Comment: если операции с БД - это DAO интерфейс и их реализация, если операции с бинами от интерфейса - это контроллер

Comment: А вот например такой метод где должен быть?

public String addUser(){
 Factory.getInstance().getUserDao().addUser(this);
 return null;
}

В доменной модели или в каком нибудь сервисном классе? Это вроде и операция с БД, а вроде и операция с бином.